# parent div and child div stays when clicked hides when body is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

html

```
  <div class="parent opt">
    <div class="child opt" id="1">
        <li>options 1</li>
        <li>options 2</li>
    </div>
   </div>

<div class="parent opt">
    <div class="child opt" id="2">
      <li>options 1</li>
      <li>options 2</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
 function toggleDiv() {
   var id = $(this).children().attr('id');
    $(".dropdown-options").hide();
   $("#"+id).toggle();
}

$('.parent').click(toggleDiv);
```

my aim is to click on the body of the page and the divs disappear, so i tried this.

```
$("body").click(function (e)
{ 
var container = $(".opt");
if(e.target.className!=container.attr("class")){

    toggleDiv().hide();
    }
});
```

setback:: when i click on child div to choose an option, it disappear, how do i get it to stay so that i can choose an option. Please help

Comment: I think you have down votes because your li's are wrapped in a div not a ul

Answer (score 0):

Sweet way...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var flag=true;
    $(".parent").click(function(){
        flag=false;
    });
    $("body").click(function(){

        if(flag) $(".parent").hide();
        flag = true;
     });
});
```

That's a pretty messy code of yours. Hiding the parent div will also hide the child div.

Comment: I am not only concern about hiding the div when i click the body. i want the div to stay when i click around inside of it.